# tar and csv.gz files

Tags: python, csv, gzip, tar

I have problem in pre-process of game churn data. The data consist of 600 per csv file as zipped as csv.gz and all csv.gz files also zipped as .tar format. When i process the data in Python, some id's doesnt match in final data. Is there anyone suggest to process that kind of data. My code is in below

```
my_file_list = [f for f in glob.glob("data/csv/*.csv.gz")]        # reading all .csv.gz (change path as per your directory)
appended_data = [] 
i = 0
for filename in my_file_list:
    headers = [*pd.read_csv(filename, nrows=1, compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False)]
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, compression='gzip', error_bad_lines=False, usecols=[c for c in headers if c not in removable_columns])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Meaning, what is your end goal?

Comment: "some id's doesn't match in final data" tells us nothing at all.  There could be a hundred things wrong.  Show us the data you get and what you don't expect.

Comment: Actually i just want to unzip .csv.gz files in a folder as csv files

Comment: See [mre]. You need to provide debugging details including sample data.